# Deleting Multiple entries in an MS-ACCESS Mailing list

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created a table that lists names and addresses of individuals.  The current table is a test table, no real values yet.  I need a way to prevent mailing labels being generated if there are multiple individuals in the table that reside at the same address.  I found the following code on Stackoverflow but can't get it to run properly.

```
SELECT (tMin.First_Name2 + ' and ' + tMax.First_Name2) AS First_Name, tMax.Last_Name2 AS Last_Name, tMax.Address1, tMax.Address2, tMax.City,    tMax.State, tMax.ZipCode, tMax.GroupCount  

FROM  
  (SELECT  Max.First_Name AS First_Name2, Max.Last_Name AS Last_Name2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*)=2    AS GroupCount   
FROM Private_Family_Information_Table         
GROUP BY Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode         
Having Count(*) = 2) AS tMax Inner Join         

(Select  Min.First_Name AS First_Name2, Min.Last_Name AS Last_Name2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*) AS GroupCount 
FROM Private_Family_Information_Table 
GROUP BY Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode         
Having Count(*) = 2) AS tMin                   

On (tMax.Address1 = tMin.Address1) And 
IIF(IsNull(tMax.Address2), '', tMax.Address2) = IIf(IsNull(tMin.Address2),'', tMin.Address2) And (tMax.City = tMin.City) And (tMax.State = tMin.State) And (tMax.ZipCode = tMin.ZipCode)    
UNION ALL 

SELECT Max(First_Name) As First_Name2, Max(Last_Name) As Last_Name2, Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode, Count(*) AS GroupCount  
FROM  Private_Family_Information_Table  
GROUP BY Address1, Address2, City, State, ZipCode Having Count(*) = 1 Or       Count(*) > 2
ORDER BY Last_Name, First_Name, State, CIty, ZipCode;
```

When I run the query in Access, I am prompted to enter an initial parameter for min.First_Name, Max.First_Name, etc. I can press cancel to cycle through all the field names it requests parameters for. Then the query runs and deletes the first and last name of the people that have the duplicate address; the duplicate address only prints once (The records with the duplicate address only print once, but there is no name associated with the address). Records with only a single instance of an address print correctly.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I would do a simple select query that groups by the address fields and selects the first item in each name field - unless you need a more sophisticated way to pick which addressee is the name you want with the duplicate address..

Comment: Wow,  I figured it out-  That is quite a bit easier.  If I had another field that further defined the dataset so that I could pick out the guardian of each family, could I also add an expression to always pick that person's first name?

Comment: It would be easiest if you could ensure every property had a guardian identified - then you could select on that field.  If some properties have a guardian & some don't, it becomes harder.  You would need some logic to get addresses with no guardians differently from addresses with a guardian - maybe a union of the 2 cases?  Not sure without seeing more data and some examples.